# Get just the text nodes constructed into a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div>
some text I want
<span><sup>text I don't want</sup></span>
</div>
```

Above is some example html. I want to be able to select just the text of the div without the child html text that is located in the span. Is there any simple way of doing this or am I going to have to come up with some way to hack away at the markup?

I've tried using jquery selectors to select just the div but when I end up calling the .text() method you end up with all of the text again... Am I missing something extremely obvious?

Comment: How are you selecting? With a mouse-event, onclick of an element..?

Comment: @DavidThomas was writing a plugin for a rich text editor to handle pasted in footnotes from word. so it was part of a process of matching existing footnotes to existing ones to prevent duplicates. I was really just over-thinking the whole problem looking for that perfect elegant solution and really, any of these are probably good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like below should get you the text,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Pga2M/1/)

```
var justText = $('div').contents().filter(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) return true;
}).text();
```

Note that this would also return you the line breaks and white space.

You can use `$.trim` to get rid of those,

```
justText = $.trim(justText);
```

Comment: This works pretty well, It solved the "simple" example I have above (don't know how I missed this in the Jquery documentation). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var text = $('div').contents().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div').clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully explained answer with the example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/xHcPU/

```
//elem.childNodes is a NodeList containing all child nodes of the array
//This includes every node - text and elements
// https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes
var childNodes = document.getElementById( 'special' ).childNodes;

//arr.reduce receives an array-like object and a callback
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

//We use func.call to call arr.reduce with the childNodes as the this variable
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
var out = [].reduce.call( childNodes, function ( ret, child ) {

    //if a node's nodeType is 3, you can safely say it's a text node
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType
    if ( child.nodeType === 3 ) {
        ret += child.nodeValue.trim();
    }
    //if it's any other node, we just ignore it
    return ret;

}, '' );

//out will now contain the string you seek
```

Do note that the two ES5 functions used here, `Array.prototype.reduce` and `String.prototype.trim`, can be easily replaced by a shim, your own implementation or, if existant, a jQuery equivalent. I do not recall a `reduce` equivalent, but I do believe there exists a `trim` one.

Comment: You should not treat host objects as if they are native objects, the above will fail in some browsers.

Comment: IE 8 and lower, at least. There is no reason to believe that host objects will behave like native objects when ECMA-262 says that they don't have to and have been shown not to.

Comment: @RobG Well, since IE8- don't have `Array.prototype.reduce`, and any shim will iterate it as if it were any other array, I don't see a problem.

Comment: —You're missing the point, it isn't the missing method, it's passing a host object as *this* to a native javascript method.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is completely unnecessary. Strip all HTML:

```
var text = node.innerHTML.replace(/<.+>/, '');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Pga2M/3/) with jQuery to select the div.

Answer (score 0):

Just collect the text of the immediate child nodes:

```
function getImmediateText(el) {
  var node, nodes = el.childNodes;
  var text = '';

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];

    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      text += node.data;
    }
  }
  // You may want to trim excess white space here
  return text;
}
```

That will work in every browser and doesn't need library support.